# How to implement page swipe animation in react native using react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am working on a react native app, and I have implemented 5 pages using `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs`. Now when the user clicks a tab, the page corresponding to the tab appears immediately without any animation.

This non-animation is ok for 4 screens, but for one I want to show "right to left" swipe animation when a users clicks the tab (ANIMATION SHOULD BE ON THE PAGE, NOT IN THE TAB). How can I do so using "react-navigation" ?

I did try using `react-navigation/material-top-tabs`, but the problem with that is it added the swipe animation for all five screens. And worse that is, if I press screen 5 when I am in screen 1, the swipe animation will show all 2nd,3rd and 4th page before moving to 5.

Thanks

Comment: Show me UI  screenshot or video